# creating an associative array with another associative array with smarty

Tags: arrays, smarty, associative

so I have one associative array {$join_options} with five entries already in it.

if I dump $join options it will show:

```
19 => Some text for 19
20 => Some text for 20
22 => Some text for 22
24 => Some text for 24
26 => Some text for 26
```

Good so far.

And if I just use `{$join_options.20}` it will print

Some text for 20

But then I try this little ditty:

```
{assign var=modified_join_options values=[
20 => '$join_options.20',
24 => '$join_options.24',
26 => '$join_options.26',
]}
```

and I get this error:

```
syntax error: invalid attribute name: ''$join_options.20',' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1550)
```

I've tried multiple different ways to type $join_options.20 I've tried with '' without with {} and without Wat do?

EDIT: I've tried adding backticks, using value instead of values, removing the last comma.  Now I get:

Smarty error: [in site:join line 116]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '=' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1550)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wound up just creating a function for smarty where I passed in the smarty object and the arrays as params. Inside the function of the plugin I do my manipulation and then use the smarty object to assign the options i want to a new array using foreach key value loops, if statements, strpos() and strtolower() functions. Pretty standard php stuff.  I don't know if this is standard procedure for smarty but I found some helpful documentation with the software I am using and it informed that this was an option.

Comment: Should I mark my answer as the answer even though it didn't solve the problem directly?

Comment: If it worked for you then I guess accept your answer. Majority of the time it's best to do the work in PHP then output to smarty since it's a template engine. Also if you used smarty 3 it has easier ways to create arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it has a `.` in it. You have to surround the variable with `backticks`. Try this.

```
{assign var=modified_join_options values=[
20 => '`$join_options.20`',
24 => '`$join_options.24`',
26 => '`$join_options.26`',
]}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl

Comment: I am now getting: Smarty error: [in site:join line 116]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '=' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1550)

Comment: Are you using smarty 2 or 3?

Comment: smarty 2.yada yada yada

Comment: 2.6.26, of course I can use $smarty.version, ugh so much easier than what I was trying

Answer (score 0):

Use value, remove the quotes and the last comma and it will work:

```
{assign var=modified_join_options value=[
20 => $join_options.20,
24 => $join_options.24,
26 => $join_options.26
]}
```

Comment: I am now getting Smarty error: [in site:join line 116]: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '=' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1550)

Comment: Are you using smarty v3 or 2?

Comment: 2.6.26 is the smarty version